# Deprecated error notice

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am doing a plugin tutorial, but it was made for wordpress v2.something.

The problem is - when I go to admin menu, under Settings - I get a notice error =>

> has_cap was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.0! Usage of user levels by plugins and themes is deprecated. Use roles and capabilities instead. in C:\wamp\www\jw\wp-includes\functions.php on line 3017

This is the relevant code:

```
<?php

if ( ! class_exists('SBC_Admin') ) {

    class SBC_Admin {

        function add_config_page() {

            if ( function_exists('add_submenu_page') ) {
                add_options_page(
                    'Seach by Category Options',
                    'Search by Category',
                    10,
                    basename(__FILE__),
                    array('SBC_Admin', 'config_page')
                );
            }
        }

        function config_page() {
            if ( isset($_POST['submit']) ) { // we're updating options

            }?>
            <div class="wrap">
                <h2>Search by category options</h2>
                <form action="" method="post" id="sbc-config">

                </form>
            </div>
            <?php
        }

    }

}

// insert into admin panel
add_action('admin_menu', array('SBC_Admin', 'add_config_page'));

?>
```

Comment: What have you done to research/debug this issue? The only WordPress function you're calling is `add_options_page()`. Have you [researched `add_options_page()` in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_options_page) to try to identify the problem?

Comment: Yes. using numbers for permissions is deprecated, so I tried 'Administrator' (because I saw that on the add_options_page page) and it didn't work, and then I saw somewhere else I could use 'administrator' (lowercase a), but options to use were not stated specifically on the add_options_page page

Comment: Why the downvote? The question is well stated and clear. I am new to WP and didn't understand the message completely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The deprecated notice is pretty clear:

> Usage of user levels by plugins and themes is deprecated. Use roles
>   and capabilities instead.

The only place you use a user level it here:

```
add_options_page(
    'Seach by Category Options',
    'Search by Category',
    10,
    basename(__FILE__),
    array('SBC_Admin', 'config_page')
);
```

See that "10"? Don't do that. Use a role, such as "administrator", or a capability instead, just like the message states.

Comment: Yea, I figured it along the way, as I said already in the comment. The problem was that the add_options_page page doesn't have valid examples.

Comment: The Codex page did have a bad link (now fixed) to the [Capabilities section of the Roles and Capabilities entry](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capabilities). But [the `add_options_page()` example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_options_page#Examples) looks to be valid? It uses the `manage_options` capability.